# How to clear logs from VSCODE using dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to clear every second what has been printed by `debugPrint` ? What I would like to have is the table with numbers that I wish to update every second. I would like to log it into my output window in VSCODE. Right now every loop would just add to the console and it becomes messy to read.

Comment: Look at the ANSI escape code to clear the terminal, add that code to your log statements

Answer (score 0):

`print("\x1B[1J"); // erase from cursor to beginning of screen`

https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797